# Detecting similar consecutive pattern from two columns

Tags: r, text, expression

```
x1= c("Sunwood", "Greengrass", "bluesky")
x2= c("Sun wood", "green", "sky Pl")

testframe = data.frame(Address1=x1, Address2=x2)
```

The output for the third column which compares both columns should say "Yes". Because "sun", "green", and "sky" are present indicating a match. How would we be able to detect it (up to three consecutive letters)

Comment: You can `substring` and use `ifelse`: `ifelse(tolower(substring(testframe$Address1, 1, 3)) == tolower(substring(testframe$Address2, 1, 3)), "yes", "no")`

Comment: Similar problem, but answer not upvoted/accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954471/r-if-a-substring-of-8-characters-in-cola-is-equal-to-a-substring-of-8-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one `tidyverse` possibility:

```
testframe %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 mutate(Res = ifelse(str_detect(str_extract(Address1, "^.{3}"), 
                          fixed(str_extract(Address2, "^.{3}"), ignore_case = TRUE)), "Yes", "No"))

    Address1 Address2 Res
1    Sunwood Sun wood Yes
2 Greengrass    green Yes
3    bluesky   sky Pl  No
```

It checks whether the first three elements from "Address1" matches (regardless of case) the first three elements from "Address2". If so, it returns "Yes", otherwise "No".

Or be setting the case manually to lower:

```
testframe %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 mutate(Res = ifelse(str_detect(tolower(str_extract(Address1, "^.{3}")), 
                                tolower(str_extract(Address2, "^.{3}"))), "Yes", "No"))
```

The same, but simplified based on the idea of @PoGibas:

```
testframe %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 mutate(Res = ifelse(tolower(str_extract(Address1, "^.{3}")) == tolower(str_extract(Address2, "^.{3}")), "Yes", "No"))
```

Or with just the base R:

```
testframe$Address1 <- as.character(testframe$Address1)  
testframe$Address2 <- as.character(testframe$Address2)

testframe$Res <- ifelse(tolower(sub("^(.{3}).*", "\\1", testframe$Address1)) %in% 
                         tolower(sub("^(.{3}).*", "\\1", testframe$Address2)), "Yes", "No")

    Address1 Address2 Res
1    Sunwood Sun wood Yes
2 Greengrass    green Yes
3    bluesky   sky Pl  No
```

Or basically the same as the idea of @PoGibas:

```
testframe$Res <- ifelse(tolower(substring(testframe$Address1, 1, 3)) %in% 
                         tolower(substring(testframe$Address2, 1, 3)), "Yes", "No")
```